# Building HTTP client / server pairs in Rust

Tags: rust

There are many high-quality HTTP clients and web application (micro-) frameworks available in Rust.

Are there sensible strategies for *deriving clients* from server specifications (or vice versa) or for building both in parallel while keeping all possible contract constraints (methods, paths, headers, bodies & their serializations) typed and in sync?

The use case is a rather large API surface of an SPA with client and backend both written in Rust. Other clients (also written in Rust) are planned.

Comment: Not sure to understand, what do you want to do ? 

You want to build an API (backend in rust) and a front-end (in rust too) and share structs used for serialization and deserialization between both ?

Comment: Exactly, but not just sharing the structs (that would be quite straightforward) but sharing the contract. I'd like to ensure / generate a matching client (or server method) for a specific API operation (including it's constraints).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialization is relatively easy to keep in sync if you stay within the Rust world - make dedicated serialization structs in a crate both server and client refer to.

As for the entire API, the best effort I'm aware of is [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/). There's a bunch of crates that aim to work with it, [okapi](https://github.com/GREsau/okapi), [paperclip](https://github.com/paperclip-rs/paperclip), [openapiv3](https://github.com/glademiller/openapiv3), and probably more if you search around. I haven't used any of them though.